# Django Docker problems

Tags: python, django, docker, networking, docker-network

I have some problems while creating my docker container for my django application.

I have my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

USER root

RUN apt-get -y update && \
apt -y install python3-pip && \
pip3 install setuptools gitpython && \
pip install django && \
pip install stripe && \
pip install django-extensions

RUN git clone https://github.com/***/***
WORKDIR /tfg/MiTfg
EXPOSE 8000/tcp


CMD python3 manage.py makemigrations
CMD python3 manage.py migrate
CMD python3 manage.py runserver localhost:8000
```

It works perfectly, now I run

**docker run --network host -p 8000:8000 1fbe**

And the output prints:

```
WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
Tienda.Categoria: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
    HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the TiendaConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
Tienda.Cliente: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
    HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the TiendaConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
Tienda.CodigoDescuento: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
    HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the TiendaConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
Tienda.ContadorSesiones: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
    HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the TiendaConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
Tienda.Pedido: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
    HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the TiendaConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
Tienda.Producto: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
    HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the TiendaConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.
Tienda.Productor: (models.W042) Auto-created primary key used when not defining a primary key type, by default 'django.db.models.AutoField'.
    HINT: Configure the DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD setting or the TiendaConfig.default_auto_field attribute to point to a subclass of AutoField, e.g. 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'.

System check identified 7 issues (0 silenced).
```

I think the problem is about connection because if I run in my browser localhost:8000 it says that no server running in that dir... so maybe is something wrong with the network between the docker and the host...??

I can run perfectly the django app when it is dowloaded in local without docker, so the app works but not in a container...

give me some help please!!!

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the **--network**, just try **docker run --publish 8000:8000 <container_id>**

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't have multiple CMD in one Dockerfile, read the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

about the problem of it not binding to the port locally, try running the command like this:
`docker run -p 8000:8000 <my_image>`